# jQuery click on li item but NOT a class in it

Tags: jquery, css

I have this cart that has many items, everyone of this is a `<li>` element set thru PHP:

```
<li class="cart-product" data-id="<?= $product->id ?>" data-rowid="" data-ison="0">
    <span class="product-lightup"><img src="<?= base_url('img/site_basics/product_lightup.png') ?>" /></span>
    <img src="<?= base_url('img/products/'.$product->image) ?>" class="product-img"/>

    <!-- PLUS/MINUS -->
    <div class="text-center product-click"><br>
        <span class="cart-plus"><img src="<?= base_url('img/site_basics/plus_sign.png') ?>" /><br>Aggiungi</span>
        <span class="cart-minus"><img src="<?= base_url('img/site_basics/minus_sign.png') ?>" /><br>Rimuovi</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Findout button -->
    <div class="text-center product-findout">
        <span class="badge">Scopri più</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

I use this jQuery to select an item:

```
$('.cart-product').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-ison') === '1'){
        $(this).itemOff();
    }else{
        $(this).itemOn();
    }
});
```

I want to remove the click event from the `li > div.product-findout`.
I tried changing the evet this way but doesn't work:

```
$('.cart-product:not(.product-findout)').click(function(){
    [...]
});
```

***[Edit]***
The code classes and sub-classes are important to be kept the same, as the jQuery gets and sets attribute to it.
I need to make the `li` item clickable AND GIVE THE `.product-findout` another link/event.
Any other way or idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching the click event to the items parent, so because of event propagation everytime you click any of the child items, the event will be **propagated** to the parent:

```
$('.cart-product').click(function() {
    alert("click");
});

$(".product-findout").click(function () {
    return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUhpd/2/)

Comment: have you tested in firefox. I've ran your fiddle and the alert fires everytime I click ".product-findout". Isn't the alert supposed to be stopped with your "event.stopPropagation();" ?

Comment: @DaveHaigh Ah I didn't, fixed in Firefox in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dUhpd/2/

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work

```
$('.cart-product').on('click', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('product-findout')) {
        if ($(this).attr('data-ison') === '1') {
            $(this).itemOff();
        } else {
            $(this).itemOn();
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/C4SJD/

Comment: sorry I forgot to remove the preceding period in the `hasClass` method.  It now works.

Comment: Still not working. I like this one as looks better and cleaner, but can't. What about a fiddle?

Comment: Will add a fiddle shortly.

Answer (score 2):

See this example on [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgvWx/1/)

I have used event propagation stop functionality to achieve this

```
$('.cart-product').click(function(){
        alert('hi');
    }).find('.product-findout').click(function(e) {
  //find the child and stop the event and bind another function
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('hi 2');
});
```

**EDIT**

Updated my answer

Comment: This is great and works. I forgot to mention I'll have to attach a link to it.

Comment: what link ? in the li element ??

Answer (score -3):

Move this outside `li`:

```
<div class="text-center product-findout">
    <span class="badge">Scopri più</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't, has to stay there.